# JavaScript string compression + PHP decompression

Tags: javascript, php, string, compression, jsonp

I'm looking for a solution to compress string in JavaScript, send it using GET (jsonp), and decompress back using PHP. The best would be to have fast code and good compression.

I've found [lz-string](https://github.com/pieroxy/lz-string) library, but looks like it does not have PHP backend. Any other similar libraries or PHP implementation of lz-string?

Comment: Why don't you just use the normal gzip compression via the browser?

Comment: With PHP you can try the gzdeflate function.

Answer (score 0):

As for client-side javascript compression check this deflate implementation:

https://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate

To decompress PHP-side all you need is gzinflate()

**Gotchas**

1. In case you want to POST the compressed data from the client to the server, it might be a good idea to base64 encode it first.
   On the server side you'll then have to call gzinflate(base64_decode($post_body));
2. Either the javascript deflate implementation or the PHP inflate implementation are not 100% correct and sometimes, rarely, gzinflate returns an error. This means if you go down this path you should have some fallback mechanism like: try POSTing compressed data. If it fails fallback to uncompressed data.
3. Keep the compression level down or your are bound to run into javascript timeout errors
4. If you plan on compressing lots of data (100+ KB), maybe on older browsers (IE <=9), you'll want to split the main deflate loop so that it asynchronously (use setTimeout) processes smaller chunks of data at a time. Ideally every chunk should not keep the JS interpreter busy for more than 100ms, otherwise you either degrade UI responsiveness or run into ugly JS-timeout popup errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try - http://rosettacode.org/wiki/LZW_compression which has implementation in JavaScript, php and other languages.

Comment: Note: there is an error in the php implementation- in decompress: it should be $w . $entry[0], instead of $w + $entry[0]

Comment: aaw there are more errors ... -.- bad job whoever coded that